# how to reload angular datatable?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using this [datatable.](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)

tried this way.

```
 var dttable = $('datatable1');
 var datatable = dttable.dataTable().api();
 datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
```

but not working.

Comment: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithAjax read it once. everything is in docs better read it and use it properly.

Comment: how can i get dtInstance on other page directive. i am refreshing it from another page